# How to link Django User model to certain Post models

Tags: django, django-models

So let's say I have a model called "Post" that looks like this:

```
    class Post(models.Model):
            title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            body = models.TextField()

            def __str__(self):
                   return self.title
```

now, say I have an option for users to create a Post on my site. How could I alter the standard User model and give it a characteristic containing all of the posts that that user has created. For example, say we have a user who has created a post. In the interactive shell that Django has, I could enter "user.posts" and It would pull up all the posts that that user has created. How could I go about this?

Comment: You add a `ForeignKey` from `Post` to the user model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding users as a foreign key to your Posts model. Try this after the "body" line and migrating.

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

To query relevant posts in a view you could then filter your Posts model by user like this:

user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Answer (score 0):

You add a `ForeignKey` from `Post` to the user model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
        editable=False
    )
```

In a view, you can link the logged in user with a post with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        from = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

The `related_name` parameter specifies the name of the relation in reverse. So the manager to access the `Post` objects related to a `User` object. So if you have a user object *`myuser`*, you can access the posts with:

```
myuser.posts.all()
```